# Ajax requests with different WordPress Address and Site Address setup

Tags: ajax

I have a user using my plugin with the following wp setup

```
WordPress Address (URL)
http://server1.theirhost.com/~acct/somewebsite.com/wordpress

Site Address (URL)
http://www.somewebsite.com
```

I am using admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) to pull the ajax url, which returns

```
http://server1.theirhost.com/~acct/somewebsite.com/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

When doing ajax requests from a page on http://www.somewebsite.com, it looks like the "same origin policy" is in effect and the requests fail.  Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: So there is no wordpress on the domain `http://somewebsite.com` ? Do a server to server request to avoid same origin policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how you're mapping `somewebsite.com`, you can probably just define `ajaxurl` differently:

`var ajaxurl = 'http://www.somewebsite.com/admin-ajax.php';`

If you need something more generalizable, you could filter `admin_url`, sniff out whether it's asking for `admin-ajax.php`, and if so, then rewrite it using `home_url()` or something like that.

Getting cross-domain ajax to work is possible (with a proxy approach, for instance) but it's best to avoid it if at all possible.